# Need some sort of MAX function that depends on other conditions

Tags: excel, vba, max, formula

Hoping someone here can help me with this. I have tried out a few different equations but "technically" work, but could easily not work if someone else didn't understand the conditions required. I want to make this 'fail-proof'.

Take this example below:

There are four possible scenarios: A score of 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Each score has multiple conditions that have to be met (this part I have completed with a pivot table and works fine). Let's say there are 5 'conditions' to be met to earn each score. Sorry for the weird formatting..

Score:........................1.........2.........3.........4

% of conditions met:   x1%....x2%....x3%....x4%

Score: ...................... = answer

**For a score of 1**: 100% of 'x1%' must be true.

**For a score of 2**: 100% of both x1 and x2 must be true.

**For a score of 3**: x1, x2 and x3 have to be 100%

**For a score of 4**: All have to be 100%.

The piece I can't figure out; There is a chance that x1 = 100%, x2 = 75%, and x3 =  100%.

The score here would still be 1. A max function would return x3, which would be incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: i can't see 5 conditions?

Comment: ,,, and what is the result if x1, x3 and x4 are met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
=IF(SUM($B2:$E2)=4,4,IF($B2 <1,0,INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B2:$E2)/($B2:$E2<1),1)-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what the Index($1:$1, Aggregate....) part of this equation is doing?

Comment: It is finding where the first cell is less than 1 and returning the column header of the column preceding it.

Comment: That is awesome. I really appreciate it!

Comment: If it works for you then please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.